# Create a random (0 ~ 5) numpy with only the number of elements(non list)

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20150519)

def makeMatrix():
    matrix = np.random.random_integers(0, 5, 40)

    return matrix


if __name__ == "__main__":

    matrix = makeMatrix()
    print(matrix, end='\n\n')
```

result ==> [4 2 0 5 2 1 2 0 0 5 5 4 3 4 5 5 0 5 3 1 3 4 3 2 2 5 5 2 1 1 0 1 3 1 5 4 4 0 4 3]

I want. How can I change only if 0 is displayed as 'nan'?
Let me know. I do not know about Python. Sorry..

Comment: So you want to get `[4 2 NaN 5 2 1 2 NaN NaN 5 5 4 ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify `matrix` so that to replace all zeros with `numpy.NaN` values - you can't do it because `np.NaN` is a float number while `matrix` contains integer numbers. You can't mix them in array. So you can get something close to what you want with different ways.

You may create `numpy array` of floats:

```
def makeMatrix():
    matrix = np.random.randint(0, 5 + 1, 10).astype(float)
    matrix[matrix == 0] = np.NaN
    return matrix

print(makeMatrix())
```

Output:

```
[ 4.  2. nan  5.  2.  1.  2. nan nan  5.]
```

You may create `list` of integers and NaN values:

```
def makeMatrix():
    matrix = np.random.randint(0, 5 + 1, 10)
    return matrix

matrix = makeMatrix()
matrix_to_display = list((val if val != 0 else np.NaN) for val in matrix)
print(matrix_to_display)
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, nan, 5, 2, 1, 2, nan, nan, 5]
```